# How to create stacked, log-scale bar chart in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to implement a stacked bar chart that's log scale in y, and I'm running into some troubles.

I can generate a stacked bar chart via commands of the following form:

```
plt.bar(x,y1, width=widths,yerr=y1err)

plt.bar(x,y2, width=widths,yerr=y2err, bottom=y1)
```

And I can generate a log bar chart via the following commands:

```
plt.bar(x,y1, width=widths,yerr=y1err, log=True)

plt.yscale('log', nonposy='clip')
```

However, when I put the two together to create a stacked log bar chart:

```
plt.bar(x,y1, width=widths,yerr=y1err, log=True)

plt.bar(x,y2, width=widths,yerr=y2err, bottom=y1, log=True)

plt.yscale('log', nonposy='clip')
```

it returns a regular log bar chart, not a stacked log bar chart. It's as if the "bottom" parameter was ignored. Further, some bars are haphazardly missing (perhaps suggesting instability/a bug in the call).

Any insight on this matter?

Cheers,

SR

Comment: A stacked log bar chart seems very hard to interpret. Could you describe why you want it and what info you expect someone to be able to get out of it?

Comment: your first call to `bar` needs to specify `bottom` since there is no zero on a log scale.